# Getting service unavailable message when sending messages to google xmpp using wokkel

Tags: python, xmpp, instant-messaging

I made a wokkel (twisted python) bot to send and receive messages from the google xmpp service. Everything (auth, presence) etc works fine. One of the requirements of our project is that we need to send broadcast messages to everyone in the list. Normal messages and replies work fin, but when i send a broadcast message, i get this service unavailable error 503 message.

There are about 1000 user in my contact list. Is this some bug in the code or is it google policy to prevent rapid messaging.

Also, how do other google bots cater to a large contact base ? does google provide a commercial solution for such applications ?

Thanks